# How to pass functions to Selenium's JavaScript executor?

Tags: java, selenium, kotlin, selenium-webdriver

Let's say I have a JS function like that:

```
function someFunction(callback) {
   callback()
}
```

and I want to call it from Selenium. for normal arguments (e.g. strings, arrays, integers, maps, HTML Elements) I can do:

```
driver.executeScript("someFunction(arguments[0])", "() => console.log('hi')")
```

and Selenium automatically converts/escapes the arguments.
but if an argument is a function, then it's passed as a string.
the call above becomes:

```
someFunction("() => console.log('hi')")
```

but it should have been:

```
someFunction(() => console.log('hi'))
```

is there a way to tell Selenium that the passed argument is a function?

Comment: you'd just pass the function and the call to the function as a string... it's a script so it's not interpreted yet, so you should be fine.   I.e. you send "someFunction(() => console.log('hi')); " along with the function you are calling: "function someFunction(callback) {
   callback()
}" ... as part of the same string... no need to pass as argument.

Comment: that makes sense for static strings. but if you want to make something generic, it's a bit more painful and you lose the benefits of Selenium arguments conversions (e.g. in maps and lists). look at the hack I had to do: https://github.com/lsoares/selenium-testing-library/blob/main/lib/src/main/kotlin/seleniumtestinglib/coreapi/Queries.kt#L16-L35

Answer (score 1):

with eval:

```
driver.executeScript("""
  var fn = eval(arguments[0])
  fn()
""", "() => console.log('hi')")
```

**Note**: I don't know how to escape quotes in java, this is python-style

Comment: that's interesting but it is only for raw status cases. if you have a map of options and one option can be a function it's not so easy. this is a hack I had to do https://github.com/lsoares/selenium-testing-library/blob/main/lib/src/main/kotlin/seleniumtestinglib/coreapi/Queries.kt#L16-L35

Comment: Not really, eval works for other types. eval("2") => number, eval("'2'") => string